# akaike criterion: ar() vs arima() in R

Tags: r

I've ve got drastic difference between AIC for ar(1) and arima(1,0,0):

```
> a <- ar(rn, lags=1)
> a$aic   
0          1          2          3          4          5          6          7 ...          
6.0215169  1.2184962  2.0020937  1.1786418  0.9002231  0.0000000  1.1728207  ... 

> b<-arima(rn, order=c(1,0,0))  
> b$aic
[1] -6840.676
```

The regression coeff are rather close though: -0.068 for ar and -0.077 for arima. 
Will greatly appreciate any comments.
Alec

Answer (score 3):

In the help to **ar()** you can read:

*aic The differences in AIC between each model and the best-fitting model.*

So, it shows you aic = 0 for the chosen ("best") model, because the difference is zero.

What **arima()** shows you is the actual aic.

For example, consider the following simulated data set:

```
set.seed(11)
d<-rnorm(100)
```

And then estimate ar and arma models:

```
ar.m<-ar(d,demean=FALSE)
ar.m
Call:
ar(x = d)

Coefficients:
      1  
-0.1847  

Order selected 1  sigma^2 estimated as  0.816
```

You see that ar selected one lag. So estimate the same model with arima:

```
arima.m<-arima(d,order=c(1,0,0))
arima.m
Call:
arima(x = d, order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
          ar1  intercept
      -0.1838    -0.1220
s.e.   0.0980     0.0756

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7995:  log likelihood = -130.72,  aic = 267.45
```

You see now, that the aic of arima.m is 267.45

Now aic calculated using the residuals of ar.m and the formula for aic:

```
ar.m.res<-ar.m$resid
rss.ar.m<-sum(ar.m.res[-1]^2)
l.ar.m<-1/(2*pi*rss.ar.m/100)^50*exp(-50)
2*2-2*log(l.ar.m)

267.5334
```

It is almost the same...